# Android: Making build using Ant build file

Tags: android

I have a script to filter src, res, libs etc. (based on the device type) from Android project folder to another specific folders. For example type 1 and type 2 device will have following structure after running the script.

```
Device_Type_1
  \src
  \res
  \libs
  \assets
  \AndroidManifest.xml

Device_Type_2
  \src
  \res
  \libs
  \assets
  \AndroidManifest.xml
```

I have to write a script to make build using the above folder names. I tried out **ant release** command but it's throwing Java compilation error.

I like to know is there any command/script where I can pass path of src, res, lib, asset and manifest file as parameters and can build project.

Comment: Geez. "throwing Java compilation error". quote that damn error. Nobody told you error messages ARE useful in debugging process?

Comment: I am not able to get error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but here's my script I use to build different apks for tablets and phones:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<property file="local.properties" />

<property environment="env" />

<property name="temp.dir" location="bin/temp" />

<property name="resource.absolute.dir" location="${temp.dir}/res" />

<property name="resource.source.dir" location="res" />

<condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
    <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
</condition>

<loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />

<fail message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using &apos;android update project&apos; or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable." unless="sdk.dir" />

<import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />

<macrodef name="prepare-temp-dir">
    <attribute name="target" default="phone" />
    <sequential>
        <delete dir="${temp.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${temp.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
        <!-- Probably should rewrite this with ant-contrib -->
        <if>
            <condition>
                <and>
                    <equals arg1="@{target}" arg2="phone" />
                </and>
            </condition>
            <then>
                <copy todir="${resource.absolute.dir}">
                    <fileset dir="${resource.source.dir}" casesensitive="no">
                        <exclude name="/*sw600dp*/**" />
                        <exclude name="/*large*/*" />
                        <exclude name="/*xlarge*/*" />
                    </fileset>
                </copy>
            </then>

            <else>
                <if>
                    <condition>
                        <and>
                            <equals arg1="@{target}" arg2="tablet" />
                        </and>
                    </condition>
                    <then>
                        <copy todir="${resource.absolute.dir}">
                            <fileset dir="${resource.source.dir}" casesensitive="no">
                                <exclude name="/*small*/**" />
                                <exclude name="/*normal*/*" />
                            </fileset>
                        </copy>
                    </then>
                </if>
            </else>
        </if>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="clean-temp-dir">
    <sequential>
        <delete dir="${temp.dir}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="release-phone">
    <echo message="Starting build procedure for target 'phone'" />
    <prepare-temp-dir target="phone" />
    <clean-temp-dir />
</target>

<target name="release-tablet">
    <echo message="Starting build procedure for target 'tablet'" />
    <prepare-temp-dir target="tablet" />
    <clean-temp-dir />
</target>
```

It just extends standard android build.xml and slightly modifies it. When build starts, I create a temp dir and copy all the resources I need for the target, then build from that temp dir.

Right now it just separates drawable folders, but you can tweak it easily to accomplish your goals

Comment: I did the same to separate Src, res and rest of files. Facing issue in compiling during build.